# regexp to match all images without link

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I use this regex to match all images. How I can rewrite it to match all images WITHOUT `</a>` in the end ?

```
preg_match_all ("/\<img ([^>]*)\/*\>/i", $text, $dst);
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using regex to parse HTML, there are HTML parsers for that in PHP.

Comment: You mean you want to find all `img` that do not have `a` as a parent?  Do you have some example input HTML?

Comment: Yes, That's Exactly What I Meant

Answer (score 1):

## soap box

I don't recommend using regex to parse an html string.

## however

However you might want to try using DOM to first loop through all the images and store them in an array.

```
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
    $array[$img->getAttribue('src')]=1;
}
```

Then loop through all links and try to find an image inside to remove from your array.

```
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a) {
    //loop to catch multiple IMGs in LINKS
    foreach ($a->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) { 
        unset($array[$img->getAttribue('src')]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use domDocument instead of a regex, the syntax here may not be right but it shoudl give you an idea.

```
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
$images_array = array();
foreach ($images as $image) {
  if ($image->parentNode->nodeName != 'a')
      echo $images_array = $image->getAttribute('src');
}
```